# Recursive function in PL/SQL ORACLE

Tags: oracle, recursion, plsql

In which scenario recursion can be used in PL/SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION factorial (
  n POSITIVE
) RETURN POSITIVE
IS
BEGIN
  IF n = 1 THEN
    RETURN n;
  ELSE
  RETURN n * factorial(n-1);
  END IF;
END;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..5 LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i || '! = ' || factorial(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

This will work but I want to know in real world when recursion is required in data base queries

Comment: Your sample code is PL/SQL, not a query.

Answer (score 3):

Depends what you mean by "required".  A recursive algorithm can always be rewritten as a loop and a loop can always be rewritten as a recursive algorithm (assuming that the language you're working with supports both loops and function calls).  Some algorithms tend to be easier to implement via recursion others tend to be easier to implement via loops.

Using recursion to compute factorials in PL/SQL is a reasonable implementation choice.  Using a loop would also be reasonable.  If you want to do it in pure SQL rather than resorting to PL/SQL, you could also

```
 select round( exp( sum( ln( level ) ) ) )
   from dual
connect by level <= <<some number>>
```

Which of various reasonable implementations you use depends on a variety of factors-- what approach you're most comfortable with, the speed of the various implementations, etc.

Comment: What he said. I would only add that, afaik, the only place recursion is actually required is in a recursive CTE. Oddly enough.

Comment: hey tomm can u explain what is CTE

Comment: @BrijanElwadhi - A CTE is a common table expression-- something in the `with` clause of a SQL statement.  A particular subset of CTEs are recursive CTEs-- a CTE that calls itself.  Most queries using recursive CTEs are traversing a hierarchy in which case you can also use the `connect by` clause.  For examples of recursive CTEs, https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/entry/converting_common_table_expressions_from

Comment: A recursive algorithm can only be written as a loop if it can have a stack with all the needed variables.